# Save and loop data in mounted hook

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I wanted to create a loop in the mounted() hook and save each rating number in an array which I created in the data() section. The loop works but only one number is displayed in the array.

data()

```
data () {
    return {
      inputValue: "",
      casinoRating: [],
    }
  },
```

mounted()

```
  mounted() {

    // save all ratings inside array
    for(let i = 0; i < this.casinos.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.casinos[i].Rating);
      this.casinoRating = this.casinos[i].Rating;
    }
  },
```

Comment: I assume you also have `casinos` as a data property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reassigning on each iteration.
You should append(`push`) instead.

Change the line to
`this.casinoRating.push(this.casinos[i].Rating);`

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using a computed property in this case:

```js
data() {
  return {
    inputValue: "",
    casinos: ['yada', 'yada']
  }
}
```

```js
computed() {
  casinoRatings() {
    let ratings = []
    this.casinos.map((rating, idx) => {
      ratings.push(rating)
    }
    return ratings
  }
}
```

Comment: `computed`s must return a value and his use case does not need a return. A method called from `mounted` would actually be the best fit

Comment: Yep, I know, the return statement just got backspaced somehow.

Comment: computed or mounted, that depends. Unless the OP has like 500 entries in the list, it's not gonna be a performance issue. Above that, computed will be better as it is only calculated "when" needed, and also is cached, unlike mounted which just runs everytime the component mounts.